# In TOSCA by using DEX we can distribute testcases, if there is dependency in test case is it possbile to distribute using DEX

Tags: tosca

I am having 100 Test cases in TOSCA by using DEX I have distributed 100 test cases to 10 users with each user I have shared 10 test cases but the second 10 Test cases have a dependency on the first 10 Test cases, now will it execute or will it show an error or have to wait until the first 10 test cases are executed

Comment: I have removed the `DEX` tag as the tag is for Android DEX code. Please read the tag description before using it.

Comment: now think about your test cases: the first 10 tests are executed on one PC, the second 10 cases are esecuted on another PC which has no idea about the first PC. What do you think would happen?